# Inherit from a virtual class and specify it during construction

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to have the class (for instance, ATLAS), that inherits from a virtual class (for instance, MAP) so, that one of the specializations of MAP can be specified in the constructor of ATLAS (for instance, physicalMap or politicalMap). I wonder if it would be possible with C++?

```
class map {...};

class physicalMap: public virtual map {...};

class politicalMap: public virtual map {...};

class atlas: public virtual map {
     atlas(int i): physicalMap(){...}
     atlas(inti, int j): politicalMap(){...}
     ...
};
```

How do I specify the specialization I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delegate constructor to "sister" (class that inherit the same base class) class constructor.

However with templates you can inherit from the template parameter and do something like that:

```
class map {...};

class physicalMap: public virtual map {...};

class politicalMap: public virtual map {...};

template<typename Map>
class atlas: public virtual Map {
     atlas(int i): Map(){...}
     ...
};

...
atlas<physicalMap> a;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need virtual inheritance for this. You may consider using template meta programming, wherein you can pass the class type itself as the template type parameter.

**Example:**

```
template<typename TargetClass>
class Map
{
    // Work with TargetClass
    // This class and the "target" class would know each other well
    //    in terms of what methods/variables are there in target class.
};

class PhysicalMap : Map<PhysicalMap>
{};
class PoliticalMap : Map<PoliticalMap>
{};
```

I have skipped `Atlas` to keep things simple (and understandable). If you need `Atlas`, you may skip these 2 intermediate classes (as inherited from `Map<>`), and instantiate  `PhysicalMap` and `PoliticalMap` this way.

```
class PoliticalMap; // non-templated
class PhysicalMap;

class Atlas
{
  // Instantiate maps 
   Map<PoliticalMap> _politicalMap;
   Map<PhysicalMap> _physicalMap;
};
```

Ideally, you need to reconsider your class design and ideology.

Answer (score 0):

The natural design here seems to use a member that points to a `map`. For example using `unique_ptr`

```
struct map
{
  virtual ~map();     // required for unique_ptr to work
  ...
};

class atlas
{
  std::unique_ptr<map> _map;
public:
  atlas(int i)
  : _map(i==0? new physicalMap():
         i==1? new politicalMap():nullptr)
  {
    if(!_map)
      throw std::runtime_error("not map");
  }
};
```

You may still inherit from `map`, then

```
class atlas : public map
{

public:
  /* implement public interface of map using _map */
};
```

although this is a bit cumbersome.